# Scrapy/Python: How to get JOBDIR setting from inside of spider?

Tags: python, scrapy

I'm running scrapy like this

`scrapy crawl somespider -s JOBDIR=crawls/somespider-1 -a input_data=data`

(For maintaining the Job state)

When something unexpected happens (eg. Connection lost)

A CloseSpider exception is raised and the spider is later scheduled to run as a cron job

I usually pass `**kwargs` inside `__init__` to the new spider crawl

However `JOBDIR` is'nt found inside **kwargs

Is there any way i can access this value from inside the spider?

Answer (score 0):

From inside the spider:
`self.crawler.settings.get("JOBDIR")`